# Differential Equations - Waves (Physics self-study suggestions)

Tags: soft-question, waves, education, differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I apologize ahead of time, in case this post is not allowed.

After taking a few courses at a community college, I've taken the fall 2013 semester off (I was accepted into a university for the spring 2014 semester). I'm really looking to spend the next 5 months on concentrated self-study to be a bit ahead of the game for next year.

I'm having trouble deciding if I should spend time studying differential equations from a rigorous mathematical point of view (DEs are a weak point of mine). On one hand, it couldn't ever HURT, but it might end up being an unnecessary drain on time.

And I'm also pondering studying from a book such as "Vibrations and Waves - A.P. French". I'm aware that MIT has a semester course taught from this book, and it also couldn't only be advantageous to know this material. I've studied from Morin's Classical Mechanics, which of course has a chapter dedicated to SHM, but this isn't exactly what I would call "in depth".

Once again, I'm sorry if this is off-topic.

Thanks for reading